# Как сократить регулярное выражение для поиска ФИО python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

У меня на вход подаются имена фамилии и (необязательно) отчества. Например 'иван иванов', 'Даня','иван петрович восков', 'Kolya'. Мне нужно отсеить те имена, где есть только имя (только одно слово) и имена, написанные не на кириллице. Я написал такое регулярное выражение `r'([А-ЯЁ]|[а-яё]+[А-ЯЁ]|[а-яё\-])+((?:\s+[А-ЯЁ]|[а-яё]+[А-ЯЁ]|[а-яё\-]+)+(?:\s+[А-ЯЁ]|[а-яё]+[А-ЯЁ]|[а-яё\-]+))?'`, но мой учитель сказал, что оно выглядит ужасно и тут вполне возможны баги. Как мне исправить это выражение?

Comment: Т.е. любая строка не на кириллице но только одно слово в строке на кириллице?

Comment: Строка не должна быть одним словом и содержать иные символы, кроме кириллицы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уот так вот

```
[А-ЯЁа-яё]+(\s+[А-ЯЁа-яё]+)+
```

Если есть переводы строки, которые не надо учитывать то так:

```
[А-ЯЁа-яё]+([^\S\r\n]+[А-ЯЁа-яё]+)+
```

Тест https://regexr.com/58ecs

Answer (score 0):

Моё решение:

```
r'([А-ЯЁа-яё])+(?:\s+[А-ЯЁа-яё]+){1,2}'
```